# Charles Proxy Flash Game

Tags: flash, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm a new user of charles proxy and didn't find any answers or tutorial.

I'm trying to see the HTTP traffic from a game. Some thing appears, but the actions doesn't appear, the host can't be SSL proxyd or if can the option to SSL proxy is not showed.

And some thing that appear in the response tab are strange charraters and I already many things to normalize but I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure: Did you check the checkbox "Enable SSL Proxying" (found in Proxy/Proxy settings/SSL)?

Then, the SSL Proxying option should appear when you rightclick any https request.

(from: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/)